# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista de menor a mayor en base a las sumas de sus matrices?

Tags: python

tengo una duda con mi programa. Tengo una lista con varias matrices y lo que hace mi programa es que calcula la suma de los números de cada matriz y la agrega al final de cada matriz. Quiero saber cómo puedo ordenar mi lista de matrices de menor a mayor en base a sus sumas.

```
mats=[[[4,-6],[8,-8]],[[3,11],[-14,-9]],[[2,1],[10,-11]],[[7,-4],[6,-7]],[[-5,-9],[12,-4]]]

for x in range(len(mats)):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(mats[x])):
        for j in range(len(mats[x])):
            sum=sum+abs(mats[x][i][j])
    mats[x].append(sum)

print(mats)
```

Comment: `sorted(mats, key=lambda x: x[-1])`

Comment: Ah, y mejor no usas `sum` como nombre de variable, pues redefines el símbolo que Python usaba para la función `sum()`.

Comment: Entendido, gracias @abulafia